# How to design 2 different layers in one activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm new at Android programming and couldn't solve how to do a design problem.

I have an activity with constraint layout, and it is full of textviews and buttons.

I want to put 6 imageview tool top of to the this activity. And there should be 3 of them should be seen on the screen, other ones should be scrolls to the right side. Like the screenshot I'm uploading.

Only these 6 imageviews should be scrolling horizontally.

I don't know what to do, which tools should I use. How can I do that design?

Thanks.

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 6 `ImageView`s scrolling horizontally, I would advise you make use of a `RecyclerView` which is very powerful in dealing with showing data in a list especially for very large data sets. You can check out how to work with a `RecyclerView` [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

Since you only have 6 `ImageView`s, you can make use of a `HorizontalScrollView`, a `LinearLayout` with `orientation` set to `horizontal` i.e `android:orientation="horizontal"` and then place your `ImageView`s inside the `LinearLayout`.

```
<HorizontalScrollView ...........>
    <LinearLayout ......>

        <ImageView......./>
        <ImageView......./>
        <ImageView......./>
        <ImageView......./>
        <ImageView......./>
        <ImageView......./>

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution here is a [`HorizontalScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView?hl=en).

As `HorizontalScrollView` only accepts one child, wrap your `ImageView`s in another layout, e.g. `LinearLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`, then put that in a `HorizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use horizontal recyclerview for imageviews and below horizontal recyclerview, you can use linear layout for textviews inside scroll view.

<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
<RecyclerView>

</RecyclerView>
<LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```